# Prove $\lim_{t\to\infty} |\frac{1}{t} \int_0^t f(x(y)) dy - \frac{1}{t} \int_s^{s+t} f(x(y))dy| = 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Here $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ is a dynamical system associated with the o.d.e. $\frac{d}{dt} x(t) = h(x(t)), t\ge 0$. Here $h$ is a continuous function and is Lipschitz. $x$ is guaranteed to be bounded, i.e., $\sup_t \| x(t) \|  < \infty$ almost surely.
$f$ is any continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^d$ that vanish at infinity. Prove that

$$\lim_{t\to\infty} \Big|\frac{1}{t} \int_0^t f(x(y)) dy - \frac{1}{t} \int_s^{s+t} f(x(y))dy\Big| = 0.$$

This problem is from the proof of V. Borkar's book Stochastic Approximation, Theorem 6. The author takes it for granted but I could not figure out why. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f$ vanishes at $\infty$ therefore it is bounded, say by $M.$ The difference of the integrals is equal
$${1\over t}\int\limits_0^sf(x(y))\,dy-{1\over t}\int\limits_t^{t+s}f(x(y))\,dy $$ The first term tends to $0,$ when $t\to\infty.$ The absolute value of second term can be estimated by
$${s\over t}\sup_{t\le y\le t+s}|f(x(y))|\le {Ms\over t}$$  Therefore the limit is indeed equal $0.$

Comment: Oh! I got it. I made a mistake. You are correct! It helps a lot! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for accepting.